# Conflicting models when overriding

Tags: django

It seems like oscar is not picking up my pointed local folder.

`INSTALLED_APP = [] + get_core_apps(['myoscar.partner'])`

My error is

`Conflicting 'partner' models in application 'partner': <class "oscar.app.partner.models.Partner"> and <class "myoscar.partner.models.Partner">`

This also leads me to another related question - there's two settings.py. I've tried adding in both. When I remove `myoscar.partner` in my main app, I obviously dont get the error but it gives me oscar's default model - which makes sense but then I run into the above error when I add it in. I don't know of anywhere else I'm registering the partner model before this override - at least not that I know of.

My question is 
1) which settings.py is the right one? I want to make sure.
2) why do I get this error when I pointed to the forked folder? Is it not picking up my folder?

App/myoscar/partner/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.partner.abstract_models import AbstractPartner

User = get_user_model()

class Partner(AbstractPartner):
    users = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='partner_user')

from oscar.apps.partner.models import * 
#per some answers on stackoverflow, I've also tried removing this but the docs say this should be added here to keep the other models.
```

my folder structure:

```
App
|--app
|----__init.py__
|----settings.py
|----urls.py
|--myoscar
|----partner
|-------models.py
|----myoscar
|------settings.py
|------urls.py
|--mysub
|----migrations
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems with related_name value. Try using a different value for it.

Comment: interesting thought whole point was to override... but when i get get_model('partner', 'Partner') it is still the same oscar model.